# Adding UILabel into Three20 API on full image display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

after integrating Three20 open source and it works good but i want to know can i add a label on full image screen which shows the description of the image. Is that possible? and how?

Can any one help me.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[self.view addSubView:myLabel];` should do the trick here. Set the size of the label equal to the size of the screen `320 * 480`.